# Prove that $S$ is isomorphism if $T:V\to W$, $U\subseteq V$, $V=U\oplus kerT$ and $S:U\to ImT$ is defined by $S(u)=T(u)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, proof-explanation

> Given:
>
> linear map $T:V\to W$
>
> $U$ is a subspace of $V$
>
> $V=U\oplus \ker T$
>
> linear map $S:U\to \operatorname{Im}T$ defined such that $S(u)=T(u)$ for all $u\in U$.
>
> Prove that $S$ is isomorphism.

We know that $\dim V=\dim U+\dim \ker T$.

On the other hand $\dim V=\operatorname{Im}T+\ker T$ from which follows that $\dim U = \dim \operatorname{Im}T.$

We can prove that $S$ is surjective and we're done.

Let $s\in \ker T, u\in U, v\in V, T(v)=w$.

Because $V=U\oplus \ker T$ then
$$v=u+s\Rightarrow w=T(v)=T(u+s)=T(u)+T(s)=T(u)+0=T(u)\quad \ast$$

**Why** **do we have** to show $\ast$? If it's given that $S(u)=T(u)$ then we already know that for any $u\in U$ there exists $T(u)$ which means that any $u\in \operatorname{Im}T$.

Comment: @MichaelHardy The problem was that I reached the character limit in the title when I used operatorname

Comment: But you used \text in the body of the question too.

Comment: oh: I'd better mention that \ker is what is actually standard in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y \in \text{Im}T$. This means $\exists x \in V$ s.t. $y = T(x)$.

You'd like to use that : $S(x)=T(x)$. But since $x \in V$, you can't use the fact that $S(u) = T(u), \forall u \in U$. $S(x)$ may have no sense !

$\ast$ shows that it actually does not really matter.

Comment: Because $x$ may be in non-$U$ part of $V$? that is $x\in V\setminus U$?

Comment: @Yos Exactly. $ $

Answer (score 1):

**Suggestion:**

It's simpler to show that $S$, which is the *restriction* of $T$ to the subspace $U$, is injective, i.e. that $\ker S=\{0\}$.

Comment: While true, this doesn't really answer OP's question.

Comment: That's right. The fact is that I don't really understand what is to be proved, and I think the O.P. is rather confused on this question. Maybe I should have entitled `Suggestion` rather than `Hint`.

Comment: How can we prove that $\text{ker}S=\{0\}$?

Comment: Since $S$ is the restriction of $T$ to $U$, obviously $\ker S=(\ker T)\cap U$.